# Managing conversion from \\ to \ in Android Java

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, escaping

We need to produce a string like this: `"\/Date()\/"`. Backslashes are not escape characters here. This is a literal string. The .NET guy on our team suggested syntax like *@"something"* but according to the Java guy, there's no such thing available yet (latest version of Android).

There's a writer and the command executed is:

```
writer.value("\\/Date(12341234123412)\\/");
```

Apparently, the output leads to the this:

> ... "Occasion":"\\/Date(12341234123412)\\/" ...

It was suggested to use a single backslash but apparently that didn't work, neither. Is it an encoding thing? Is there a general hint in Android environment for such things?

There's a work-around if we make changes to the API but that means server side needs changing (into worse design, not following standards) and me needing to rewrite what I'm serving. And when we get the code from our iPhone girl, she'll need to change it too. So it seems wiser to give the guy a push on Java side.

Apparently there's no default serializers for an object to JSON on Android and it take a lot of work to design one. I find the latter very true but the former unexpected. Still, it's only a POC so it's OK to hard-code the string for now.

He got most of the communication running. It's just the JSON chunk that's problematic.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "apparently, the output leads to the this"? What is `writer`? The value you're writing does have a single backslash, so it sounds like something else *may* be escaping the value, but we can't tell without more information...

Comment: @JonSkeet The communication isn't the best in this case so I have no such information (not because of lack of trying, hehe). I was hoping there was a nice, standard way to do it that most Andorid devs know but I'm ignorant about. If there's none, then I'll remove the question because it's pointless. It seems weird that the serialization to JSON would be such a pain on Android... Perhaps we need a more collaborative Android guy, hehe.

Comment: I think without any more information, it's going to be very hard to see the difference between an answer which actually helps and one which would be applicable in a different context. Even just knowing the type of `writer` here would help.

Comment: according to your update, this is not the normal behaviour. So like @JonSkeet said, we need to know what `writer` you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if i got the question correctly.
But if you want to produce a Javascript-String-Syntax, you may want to have \ in there. So You would have to produce two backslahes and for that, you have to write four of them (one to escape each).

`"\\\\/Date(12341234123412)\\\\/"` would create a String `\\/Date(12341234123412)\\/` and if you write this to javascriptsyntax, it is therefore a String with excpected backslashes.

Maybe better clarified:

- Java Syntax: `"\\\\/Date(12341234123412)\\\\/"`
- String in Memory: `\\/Date(12341234123412)\\/`
- now it will be written in a javascript-file, surrounded with doublequotes
- Javascript Syntax `"\\/Date(12341234123412)\\/"`
- String in Memory `\/Date(12341234123412)\/`

Comment: But you said: "Apparently, the output leads to the this:

    ... "Occasion":"\/Date(12341234123412)\/" ...", so your result has only one "\". So it is already working?

Comment: I see your example. It's precisely what we expected. Apparently it "*didn't work*". No idea why or how it failed. And I'm in no position to ask the guy himself. I'm just trying not to need to rewrite my iPhone code, WinPhone code and making the back-end dev changing in API just because a dev got confused on strings, hehe. SOrry for the vague question. I put that in the disclaimer.

Comment: Edited the question. It was SO that interpreted my \\ and \, hehe. +1 for keen eyes, anyway.

Comment: I'll comment above to your question.